# how do I fix this MySQL DELETE query?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, `products`, `shops`, and `sex`. I wish to `DELETE` rows in the products table having a `product_id` such that there exists no equivalent `product_id` in the `sex` table.

Further, these rows in the `products` table must have a `shop_id` equal to the `shop_id` in the `shops` table for the row whose `shops.shop` value is 'www.shop.com'.

so far I have

```
DELETE FROM products USING shops WHERE
products.shop_id=shops.shop_id AND
shops.shop='www.shop.com' AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT sex.product_id FROM sex WHERE
sex.product_id=products.product_id)
```

but it appears it is not acceptable to make reference to `products` in the subquery as I have done. (I get the error `Unknown table 'products' in MULTI DELETE`.) How do I fix my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JOIN`s in your `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE    a 
FROM      products a
JOIN      shops b ON a.shop_id = b.shop_id AND b.shop = 'www.shop.com'
LEFT JOIN sex c ON a.product_id = c.product_id
WHERE     c.product_id IS NULL
```

This will `DELETE` only the products which have a corresponding row in the `shops` table with `shop` = www.shop.com, but only if that product also does ***not*** have a corresponding row in the `sex` table.

Comment: that worked great. I am curious, if I wanted to do the `DELETE` not based on `c.product_id IS NULL` but on, say, `(ADDDATE(c.date,INTERVAL 24 HOUR) >= NOW())` and also `DELETE` these matching rows from the `sex` table, would I use `DELETE a,c` instead of `DELETE a`?